# Peculiar Numbers

Tags: mathematics

Apart from the regular numbers, now we will reform the numbers and call them **peculiar numbers**. We will consider the numbers in range of **[1-9]**.

This is how the peculiar numbers are different from regular numbers.

> - Every peculiar number is processed in this way;
> - x is any number and it's peculiar form is **( x + x - x * x )^x**  (You take care of operation priority)

Now the problem is how to reshape the operations so that results become same as in regular numbers.

> Example:
>
> - 3 + 2 = 5
> - Peculiar(3) + Peculiar(2) must be 5
> - Here, we have to reform the **+** so that the peculiar operation gives 5 again.

But here we have to think about all numbers between **[1-9]** and these operations **+, -, x, /**. An example solution will be like;

> The new form of addition sign is like
>
> - a + b = a^b + b*a - b

Comment: not Peculiar(5)?

Comment: did you prove by putting values? I do not know the answer

Comment: are we going for Peculiar(2)+Peculiar(3)=Peculiar(5) or Peculiar(2)+Peculiar(3)=5? the first looks more interesting...

Comment: it will result same as in regular numbers so answer will be 5 not peculiar(5)

Comment: What about the ”^”? Is it exponentiation, bitwise xor, something else, or do we get to redefine it? If it’s an exponent (which is repeated multiplication), will it be affected by our redefining multiplication, or will it keep its usual definition?

Comment: no  just main operators +, - ,/ ,x

Comment: Do you actually have an answer for this? I ask because I see no reason for any explicit expression for these operators to exist (except for stupid polynomial constructions that are essentially the same as a table look-up).

Answer (score 1):

I'll use $p_1$ to $p_9$ to mean the values Peculiar(1) to Peculiar(9).

Consider the following function:

$$D_k(x) = \prod_{i\neq k} \frac{x-p_i}{i-p_i}$$

So for example

$$D_2(x) = \frac{(x-p_1)(x-p_3)(x-p_4)(x-p_5)(x-p_6)(x-p_7)(x-p_8)(x-p_9)}{(2-p_1)(2-p_3)(2-p_4)(2-p_5)(2-p_6)(2-p_7)(2-p_8)(2-p_9)}$$

This function is constructed such that

$$D_k(p_i) = \begin{cases}  
1, & i = k \\
0, & i \ne k
\end{cases}$$

You can now construct any peculiar operator as follows.

$$a+_{peculiar}b = \sum_{i=1}^9 \sum_{j=1}^9 D_i(a)\cdot D_j(b)\cdot(i+j)\\
a\times_{peculiar}b = \sum_{i=1}^9 \sum_{j=1}^9 D_i(a)\cdot D_j(b)\cdot(i\cdot j)$$

etc.

For any peculiar numbers $a$ and $b$, only one of the terms in the double sum is non-zero, and it contributes exactly the value that you want the operator to have for those $a$ and $b$. It is basically a glorified look-up table encoded into a complicated expression. This does not use any particular properties of the peculiar numbers except for the fact that they are all distinct.

Answer (score 0):

Let's denote the set of peculiar numbers $P = \{ (2n-n^2)^n : n \in \{ 1,2, \dots ,9 \} \} $
Our goal is to define functions:
$$ +_P:P^2 \to \mathbb{N} $$
$$ -_P:P^2 \to \mathbb{N} $$
$$ \cdot_P:P^2 \to \mathbb{N} $$
$$ /_P:P^2 \to \mathbb{N} $$

We're working in finite space, so we can define a function by values
$dp: P \to \mathbb{N} $
$$ dp(a) = \begin{cases}  
1, & a = 1 \\
2, & a = 0 \\
3, & a = -27 \\
\vdots \\
9, & a = 28179280429056
\end{cases} $$

Then it's very easy to define required functions (note that operators on the left hand side are from $P$, while the ones on the right are standard operators in $\mathbb{N}$
$$ p  +_P  q = dp(p) + dp(q) $$
$$ p -_P q = dp(p) - dp(q) $$
$$ p \cdot_P q = dp(p) \cdot dp(q) $$
$$ p /_P q = dp(p) / dp(q) $$